# Second harmonic generation (SHG) in centrosymmetry material

Tags: non-linear-optics

I know SHG in centrosymmetry material is not possible as "$E(t)\rightarrow -E(t)$" and "$P(t) \rightarrow -P(t)$" one should get the same $P(t)$. I am confused why $E(t)$ and $P(t)$ should change their signs while $r \rightarrow -r$? $E(t)$ should be an external source and is not dependent on the location of the dipoles, right? I know I am wrong but can anyone make it clearer please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Centrosymmetric means that a change of coordinates $r\rightarrow -r$ results in no change to the system.  Thus the relationships you quote of $E$ and $P$ must hold. And the locations of the dipoles (well, molecules) also does not change.   Can you clarify what is confusing to you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand why $r\rightarrow-r$ indicates $E\rightarrow-E$ and $P\rightarrow-P$.

Comment: Another way to look at it is physically.  If the system remains unchanged when I invert, then a reversal of $E$ will result in a reversal of $P$.  The polarizability is isotropic.  You get the same polarization (except the sign) when you reverse the field.  It has to be!  The system looks the same regardless of what direction we look.

Comment: @garyp Maybe your comments should be made an answer.